# UILabel View with rounded corner radius does not work on iOS 17 Beta - Xcode 15 Beta

Tags: ios, storyboard, uilabel, ios17

I am using a UILabel view and I have set the corner radius of it so as to make it rounded using runtime attributes.
[image]

This is how it appears on iOS 16.x or below (any iOS 16 or below).
[image]

and this is how it looks on iOS 17 Beta.
[image]

The dot appears like a square. no idea how to fix this.

Tested on multiple devices and the square issue only appears on iOS 17 Beta.

Comment: Do not misuse a label to make a filled circle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this after creating the corner radius:

```
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Thank you matt for the negative vote. I was facing the same problem with a label used as a badge number and this solved the problem. There are other multiple uses of a label with background and cornerradius, not only for creating an empty circle. My answer is right, and the vote should adjusts to the correction of the issue and not being based in what's this programmer choosing to create the circle.